# Button in popup is disabled for Material Design in Xaml toolkit for wpf

Tags: wpf, materialdesignthemes

I am using material design toolkit to show code in popup. I am following the reference from this github repo: https://github.com/Keboo/ShowMeTheXAML In the pop-up there is a copy button. But it is staying disabled. I wounder am I missing something! If anyone used this toolkit and faced this problem could suggest a solution.

```
<showMeTheXaml:XamlDisplay Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" UniqueKey="XamlNormalTextBoxStyle">
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource NormalTextBoxStyle}" 
                         TextAlignment="Center" 
                         Width="230" 
                         Margin="0,30" 
                         Text="This is the standard usage of textbox"/>
            </showMeTheXaml:XamlDisplay>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="smtx:XamlDisplay">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <materialDesign:PopupBox DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                                     IsTabStop="False" Padding="10" StaysOpen="True" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                     VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                                     x:Name="PopupBox">
                                <materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Xml" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="View XAML" 
                                                             Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkBrush}" 
                                                             Background="Transparent" 
                                                             Margin="3">
                                        <materialDesign:PackIcon.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="materialDesign:PackIcon" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:PackIcon}}">
                                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4" />
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </materialDesign:PackIcon.Style>
                                    </materialDesign:PackIcon>
                                </materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
                                <Border MaxHeight="600" MaxWidth="800">
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <Button
                                            Margin="0 10 0 0"
                                            Tag="{Binding Xaml, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            Command="Copy"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding Xaml, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                            Content="_COPY"
                                            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}">
                                        </Button>
                                        <avalonedit:TextEditor Document="{Binding Xaml, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource TextDocumentValueConverter}}" 
                                                               Style="{StaticResource AvalonTextEditorXamlDisplay}" />
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </Border>

                            </materialDesign:PopupBox>
                            <Grid>
                                <AdornerDecorator>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SecondaryHueMidBrush}" Opacity=".4" Margin="-5">
                                        <Border.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=PopupBox, Path=IsPopupOpen}" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Border.Style>
                                    </Border>
                                </AdornerDecorator>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Grid>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the code segment of button with the following:

```
<DockPanel>
            <materialDesign:Badged
             x:Name="CopyBadge" BadgeColorZoneMode="PrimaryDark"
             DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
             HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                  <Button
                   Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedLightButton}"
                   Tag="{Binding Xaml, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding Xaml, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                   Click="CopyButton_OnClick"
                   Content="Copy"/>
             </materialDesign:Badged>
             <avalonedit:TextEditor Document="{Binding Xaml, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource TextDocumentValueConverter}}" 
             Style="{StaticResource AvalonTextEditorXamlDisplay}" />
</DockPanel>
```

And added a handler for the click event in the app.xaml.cs as below:

```
private void CopyButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var xamlValue = ((Button)sender).Tag;
            Clipboard.SetText(xamlValue.ToString());
        }
```

And it is working as expected.